# SELECT strftime('%m %d, %Y', orderDate) FROM tblOrderMaster

Tags: javascript, sqlite, sencha-touch

I am trying to select date from table with formating it but unfortunately it is not working.

Works:

```
SELECT strftime('%m %d, %Y', 'now') FROM TABLE_NAME
```

DOES NOT WORKS:

```
SELECT strftime('%m %d, %Y', TABLE_FIELD_NAME) FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use one of the [supported date/time formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime) for the values in the table, it works just fine:

```
> CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME(TABLE_FIELD_NAME);
> INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES('2013-05-29');
> SELECT strftime('%m %d, %Y', TABLE_FIELD_NAME) FROM TABLE_NAME;
05 29, 2013
```